# Find mysql entries with common tags

Tags: php, mysql, tags

I have articles stored in a MySQL table. Now I want to display related articles. So I integrated a field called "tags", which stores all tags separated by commas. Until now I search for common tags like this:

```
    foreach (explode(',', $article['tags']) as $key => $value) {
        if ($key != 0)
            $search.= ' OR';
        $search .= " `tags` LIKE '%" . mysql_real_escape_string($value) . "%'";
    }
    $query = "SELECT title, id  FROM `article` WHERE $search";
```

That created a query like this:

```
SELECT title, id FROM `article` WHERE `tags` LIKE '%tag1%' OR `tags` LIKE '%tag2%'
```

I am wondering if there is a more efficient way to solve this. The negative side of my current solution is the "%" which causes that extreme short Tags like "green" collide with "greenteam" .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should store your tags in a different table "tag" and add relationships between each article and tag in an another table called "article_tag" for example.

**TABLES**

```
article
=======
id
title
...

tag
=======
id
label

article_tag
=======
article_id
tag_id
```

**QUERY**

```
SELECT article.id, article.title 
FROM article
JOIN article_tag ON article_tag.article_id = article.id
JOIN tag ON article_tag.tag_id = tag.id
WHERE tag.label IN ('tag1', 'tag2')
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to create the following table scheme?  
`article  
====  
id  
title  
...  
  
tags  
====  
article_id  
tag`  
  
It makes your third table dispensable. I have to run two queries then:  
`Select article_id FROM tags where tag = 'tag1' or tag = 'tag2' `  
`Select title, id FROM article where id = '$id'`  
Can I somehow combine them?

Comment: You could but it's cleaner with the article_tag table.

I guess you can combine you queries like this : 

`SELECT article.title, article.id FROM article JOIN tags ON tag.article_id = article.id WHERE tags.tag IN ('tag1', 'tag2')`

Comment: This one should works (an s was missing to tags): `SELECT article.title, article.id FROM article JOIN tags ON tags.article_id = article.id WHERE tags.tag IN ('tag1', 'tag2')`